# What does this Excel VBA function do?

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know how to read VBA (excel). Can you help me and translate this function?

```
Function calculateDigit(value)
lenval = Len(value)
factor = 3
Sum = 0
For Index = lenval To 1 Step -1
    Sum = Sum + (CInt(Mid(value, Index, 1)) * factor)
    factor = 4 - factor
Next
calculateDigit = ((1000 - Sum) Mod 10)
End Function
```

Comment: Translate to what?

Comment: in a module step through this and see how the variables change and what is happening. Whatever the last number in the value is, is multiplied by three and then the next number in that value to the left is multiplied by 1 and added to the sum.and so on. create a formula with the function =calculateDigit(456789) ot =calculateDigit(A1)  and place a number in A1 to see how this behaves, by placing a breakpoint and stepping through the function as it operates, the rest of the function subtracts the sum from 1000 and then uses the Mod function to determine a remainder. of Mod 10

Comment: @datatoo, why not add that as an answer?

Comment: It is roughly equivalent to the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).  Typically used to add an extra digit to a number, meant to verify that it was entered correctly.